# Spark1.6.0 on Yarn with Python2.6.6 from IPython 1.2.0 - crashes

Tags: python, hadoop, ipython, pyspark, jupyter

I am trying to setup a JupyterHub instance to connect to a Hadoop Yarn cluster to run PySpark jobs.
Unfortunately the Hadoop cluster only has Python 2.6.6, so I have to run Python 2.6 on my side too and so I cannot use the recent versions of IPython, only version 1.2 (the most recent versions of IPython only runs on Python 2.7+).

I setup everything, but the IPython kernel keep crashing and restarting itself.

Below are the settings:
IPython kernel:

```
{
 "display_name": "PySpark-1.6.0 - Python2.6.6",
 "language": "python",
 "argv": [
  "/usr/local/bin/python2.6",
  "-m",
  "IPython.__main__",
  "--config={connection_file}"
 ],
 "env": {
  "SPARK_HOME": "/usr/lib/spark-1.6.0-bin-without-hadoop",
  "SCALA_HOME": "/usr/lib/scala",
  "HADOOP_USER_NAME": "myuser",
  "HADOOP_CONF_DIR": "/usr/lib/spark-1.6.0-bin-without-hadoop/yarn-conf",
  "HADOOP_HOME": "/usr/bin/hadoop",
  "YARN_HOME": "",
  "SPARK_DIST_CLASSPATH": "/etc/hadoop/conf:/usr/lib/hadoop/lib/*:/usr/lib/hadoop/.//*:/usr/lib/hadoop-hdfs/./:/usr/lib/hadoop-hdfs/lib/*:/usr/lib/hadoop-hdfs/.//*:/usr/lib/hadoop-yarn/lib/*:/usr/lib/hadoop-yarn/.//*:/usr/lib/hadoop-mapreduce/lib/*:/usr/lib/hadoop-mapreduce/.//*",
  "SPARK_LIBRARY_PATH": "/usr/lib/hadoop/lib",
  "SPARK_CLASSPATH": "/usr/lib/hadoop/lib",
  "PATH": "/usr/lib64/qt-3.3/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/sbin:/apps/home/zoltan.fedor/.local/bin:/apps/home/zoltan.fedor/bin:/usr/bin/hadoop/bin",
  "PYTHONPATH": "/usr/lib/spark-1.6.0-bin-without-hadoop/python/:/usr/lib/spark-1.6.0-bin-without-hadoop/python/lib/py4j-0.8.2.1-src.zip",
  "PYTHONSTARTUP": "/usr/lib/spark-1.6.0-bin-without-hadoop/python/pyspark/shell.py",
  "PYSPARK_SUBMIT_ARGS": "--master yarn --deploy-mode client --jars /usr/lib/avro/avro-mapred.jar,/usr/lib/spark-1.6.0-bin-without-hadoop/lib/spark-examples-1.6.0-hadoop2.2.0.jar pyspark-shell",
  "SPARK_YARN_USER_ENV": "PYTHONPATH=/usr/lib/spark-1.6.0-bin-without-hadoop/python/:/usr/lib/spark-1.6.0-bin-without-hadoop/python/lib/py4j-0.8.2.1-src.zip"
 }
}
```

And below is the ipykernel log, at least one iteration. It just keeps repeating the same as it is restarting as it crashes:

```
[I 2016-01-20 20:20:34.336 zoltan.fedor restarter:103] KernelRestarter: restarting kernel (1/5)
WARNING:root:kernel 216d7905-1d93-4052-b5b6-3aee9d3628b1 restarted
/usr/local/lib/python2.6/site-packages/path.py:1719: DeprecationWarning: path is deprecated. Use Path instead.
  warnings.warn(msg, DeprecationWarning)
Python 2.6.6 (r266:84292, Jan 20 2016, 18:10:40) 
Type "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.

IPython 1.2.0 -- An enhanced Interactive Python.
?         -> Introduction and overview of IPython's features.
%quickref -> Quick reference.
help      -> Python's own help system.
object?   -> Details about 'object', use 'object??' for extra details.
16/01/20 20:20:35 INFO spark.SparkContext: Running Spark version 1.6.0
16/01/20 20:20:35 WARN spark.SparkConf: 
SPARK_CLASSPATH was detected (set to '/usr/lib/hadoop/lib').
This is deprecated in Spark 1.0+.

Please instead use:
 - ./spark-submit with --driver-class-path to augment the driver classpath
 - spark.executor.extraClassPath to augment the executor classpath

16/01/20 20:20:35 WARN spark.SparkConf: Setting 'spark.executor.extraClassPath' to '/usr/lib/hadoop/lib' as a work-around.
16/01/20 20:20:35 WARN spark.SparkConf: Setting 'spark.driver.extraClassPath' to '/usr/lib/hadoop/lib' as a work-around.
16/01/20 20:20:35 INFO spark.SecurityManager: Changing view acls to: zoltan.fedor,myuser
16/01/20 20:20:35 INFO spark.SecurityManager: Changing modify acls to: zoltan.fedor,myuser
16/01/20 20:20:35 INFO spark.SecurityManager: SecurityManager: authentication disabled; ui acls disabled; users with view permissions: Set(zoltan.fedor, myuser); users with modify permissions: Set(zoltan.fedor, myuser)
16/01/20 20:20:36 INFO util.Utils: Successfully started service 'sparkDriver' on port 41092.
16/01/20 20:20:36 INFO slf4j.Slf4jLogger: Slf4jLogger started
16/01/20 20:20:36 INFO Remoting: Starting remoting
16/01/20 20:20:36 INFO Remoting: Remoting started; listening on addresses :[akka.tcp://sparkDriverActorSystem@10.xxx.xxx.xxx:41725]
16/01/20 20:20:36 INFO util.Utils: Successfully started service 'sparkDriverActorSystem' on port 41725.
16/01/20 20:20:36 INFO spark.SparkEnv: Registering MapOutputTracker
16/01/20 20:20:36 INFO spark.SparkEnv: Registering BlockManagerMaster
16/01/20 20:20:36 INFO storage.DiskBlockManager: Created local directory at /tmp/blockmgr-b68b3c8c-c43b-4e3d-9efd-6534f7eddcaf
16/01/20 20:20:36 INFO storage.MemoryStore: MemoryStore started with capacity 511.1 MB
16/01/20 20:20:36 INFO spark.SparkEnv: Registering OutputCommitCoordinator
16/01/20 20:20:36 INFO server.Server: jetty-8.y.z-SNAPSHOT
16/01/20 20:20:36 INFO server.AbstractConnector: Started SelectChannelConnector@0.0.0.0:4040
16/01/20 20:20:36 INFO util.Utils: Successfully started service 'SparkUI' on port 4040.
16/01/20 20:20:36 INFO ui.SparkUI: Started SparkUI at http://10.xx.xx.xx:4040
16/01/20 20:20:36 INFO spark.HttpFileServer: HTTP File server directory is /tmp/spark-ba928a28-64a6-4c70-b4cf-8c348140e89e/httpd-7892e967-247d-469e-96fb-79ad9269e569
16/01/20 20:20:36 INFO spark.HttpServer: Starting HTTP Server
16/01/20 20:20:36 INFO server.Server: jetty-8.y.z-SNAPSHOT
16/01/20 20:20:36 INFO server.AbstractConnector: Started SocketConnector@0.0.0.0:43883
16/01/20 20:20:36 INFO util.Utils: Successfully started service 'HTTP file server' on port 43883.
16/01/20 20:20:36 INFO spark.SparkContext: Added JAR file:/usr/lib/avro/avro-mapred.jar at http://10.xx.xx.xx:43883/jars/avro-mapred.jar with timestamp 1453321236776
16/01/20 20:20:36 INFO spark.SparkContext: Added JAR file:/usr/lib/spark-1.6.0-bin-without-hadoop/lib/spark-examples-1.6.0-hadoop2.2.0.jar at http://10.xxx.xxx.xxx:43883/jars/spark-examples-1.6.0-hadoop2.2.0.jar with timestamp 1453321236887
16/01/20 20:20:37 INFO yarn.Client: Requesting a new application from cluster with 106 NodeManagers
16/01/20 20:20:37 INFO yarn.Client: Verifying our application has not requested more than the maximum memory capability of the cluster (192512 MB per container)
16/01/20 20:20:37 INFO yarn.Client: Will allocate AM container, with 896 MB memory including 384 MB overhead
16/01/20 20:20:37 INFO yarn.Client: Setting up container launch context for our AM
16/01/20 20:20:37 INFO yarn.Client: Setting up the launch environment for our AM container
16/01/20 20:20:37 INFO yarn.Client: Preparing resources for our AM container
16/01/20 20:20:37 WARN util.NativeCodeLoader: Unable to load native-hadoop library for your platform... using builtin-java classes where applicable
16/01/20 20:20:37 INFO yarn.Client: Uploading resource file:/usr/lib/spark-1.6.0-bin-without-hadoop/lib/spark-assembly-1.6.0-hadoop2.2.0.jar -> hdfs://Cluster/user/myuser/.sparkStaging/application_1453104838332_22373/spark-assembly-1.6.0-hadoop2.2.0.jar
16/01/20 20:20:38 INFO yarn.Client: Uploading resource file:/usr/lib/spark-1.6.0-bin-without-hadoop/python/lib/pyspark.zip -> hdfs://Cluster/user/myuser/.sparkStaging/application_1453104838332_22373/pyspark.zip
16/01/20 20:20:38 INFO yarn.Client: Uploading resource file:/usr/lib/spark-1.6.0-bin-without-hadoop/python/lib/py4j-0.9-src.zip -> hdfs://Cluster/user/myuser/.sparkStaging/application_1453104838332_22373/py4j-0.9-src.zip
16/01/20 20:20:38 INFO yarn.Client: Uploading resource file:/tmp/spark-ba928a28-64a6-4c70-b4cf-8c348140e89e/__spark_conf__4853045545116393897.zip -> hdfs://Cluster/user/myuser/.sparkStaging/application_1453104838332_22373/__spark_conf__4853045545116393897.zip
16/01/20 20:20:38 INFO spark.SecurityManager: Changing view acls to: zoltan.fedor,myuser
16/01/20 20:20:38 INFO spark.SecurityManager: Changing modify acls to: zoltan.fedor,myuser
16/01/20 20:20:38 INFO spark.SecurityManager: SecurityManager: authentication disabled; ui acls disabled; users with view permissions: Set(zoltan.fedor, myuser); users with modify permissions: Set(zoltan.fedor, myuser)
16/01/20 20:20:38 INFO yarn.Client: Submitting application 22373 to ResourceManager
16/01/20 20:20:38 INFO impl.YarnClientImpl: Submitted application application_1453104838332_22373
16/01/20 20:20:39 INFO yarn.Client: Application report for application_1453104838332_22373 (state: ACCEPTED)
16/01/20 20:20:39 INFO yarn.Client: 
     client token: N/A
     diagnostics: N/A
     ApplicationMaster host: N/A
     ApplicationMaster RPC port: -1
     queue: root.myuser
     start time: 1453321238567
     final status: UNDEFINED
     tracking URL: http://c14xx.xx.xxx.com:8088/proxy/application_1453104838332_22373/
     user: myuser
16/01/20 20:20:40 INFO yarn.Client: Application report for application_1453104838332_22373 (state: ACCEPTED)
16/01/20 20:20:41 INFO yarn.Client: Application report for application_1453104838332_22373 (state: ACCEPTED)
16/01/20 20:20:42 INFO yarn.Client: Application report for application_1453104838332_22373 (state: ACCEPTED)
16/01/20 20:20:43 INFO yarn.Client: Application report for application_1453104838332_22373 (state: ACCEPTED)
16/01/20 20:20:44 INFO yarn.Client: Application report for application_1453104838332_22373 (state: ACCEPTED)
16/01/20 20:20:45 INFO yarn.Client: Application report for application_1453104838332_22373 (state: ACCEPTED)
16/01/20 20:20:46 INFO yarn.Client: Application report for application_1453104838332_22373 (state: ACCEPTED)
16/01/20 20:20:47 INFO yarn.Client: Application report for application_1453104838332_22373 (state: ACCEPTED)
16/01/20 20:20:48 INFO cluster.YarnSchedulerBackend$YarnSchedulerEndpoint: ApplicationMaster registered as NettyRpcEndpointRef(null)
16/01/20 20:20:48 INFO cluster.YarnClientSchedulerBackend: Add WebUI Filter. org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.webproxy.amfilter.AmIpFilter, Map(PROXY_HOSTS -> c14xx.xxx.xxx.com,c141xx.xxx.xxx.com, PROXY_URI_BASES -> http://c14xx.xxx.xxx.com:8088/proxy/application_1453104838332_22373,http://c141xx.xxx.xxx.com:8088/proxy/application_1453104838332_22373), /proxy/application_1453104838332_22373
16/01/20 20:20:48 INFO ui.JettyUtils: Adding filter: org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.webproxy.amfilter.AmIpFilter
16/01/20 20:20:48 INFO yarn.Client: Application report for application_1453104838332_22373 (state: ACCEPTED)
16/01/20 20:20:49 INFO yarn.Client: Application report for application_1453104838332_22373 (state: RUNNING)
16/01/20 20:20:49 INFO yarn.Client: 
     client token: N/A
     diagnostics: N/A
     ApplicationMaster host: 10.xx.xx.xx
     ApplicationMaster RPC port: 0
     queue: root.myuser
     start time: 1453321238567
     final status: UNDEFINED
     tracking URL: http:/c14xx.xxx.xxx.com:8088/proxy/application_1453104838332_22373/
     user: myuser
16/01/20 20:20:49 INFO cluster.YarnClientSchedulerBackend: Application application_1453104838332_22373 has started running.
16/01/20 20:20:49 INFO util.Utils: Successfully started service 'org.apache.spark.network.netty.NettyBlockTransferService' on port 38421.
16/01/20 20:20:49 INFO netty.NettyBlockTransferService: Server created on 38421
16/01/20 20:20:49 INFO storage.BlockManagerMaster: Trying to register BlockManagerxx.xx.xx, 38421)
16/01/20 20:20:49 INFO storage.BlockManagerMaster: Registered BlockManager
16/01/20 20:20:58 INFO cluster.YarnClientSchedulerBackend: Registered executor NettyRpcEndpointRef(null) (c25xx.xx.xx.com:43637) with ID 1
16/01/20 20:20:58 INFO storage.BlockManagerMasterEndpoint: Registering block manager c25xx.xx.xx.com:42471 with 511.1 MB RAM, BlockManagerId(1, c25xx.xx.xx.com, 42471)
16/01/20 20:20:59 INFO cluster.YarnClientSchedulerBackend: Registered executor NettyRpcEndpointRef(null) (c214xx.xxx.xxx.com:59623) with ID 2
16/01/20 20:20:59 INFO storage.BlockManagerMasterEndpoint: Registering block manager c214xx.xxx.xxx.com.com:45327 with 511.1 MB RAM, BlockManagerId(2, c214xx.xxx.xxx.com.com, 45327)
16/01/20 20:20:59 INFO cluster.YarnClientSchedulerBackend: SchedulerBackend is ready for scheduling beginning after reached minRegisteredResourcesRatio: 0.8
Welcome to
      ____              __
     / __/__  ___ _____/ /__
    _\ \/ _ \/ _ `/ __/  '_/
   /__ / .__/\_,_/_/ /_/\_\   version 1.6.0
      /_/

Using Python version 2.6.6 (r266:84292, Jan 20 2016 18:10:40)
SparkContext available as sc, SQLContext available as sqlContext.

In [1]: 
Do you really want to exit ([y]/n)? 
16/01/20 20:20:59 INFO handler.ContextHandler: stopped o.s.j.s.ServletContextHandler{/metrics/json,null}
16/01/20 20:20:59 INFO handler.ContextHandler: stopped o.s.j.s.ServletContextHandler{/stages/stage/kill,null}
16/01/20 20:20:59 INFO handler.ContextHandler: stopped o.s.j.s.ServletContextHandler{/api,null}
16/01/20 20:20:59 INFO handler.ContextHandler: stopped o.s.j.s.ServletContextHandler{/,null}
16/01/20 20:20:59 INFO handler.ContextHandler: stopped o.s.j.s.ServletContextHandler{/static,null}
16/01/20 20:20:59 INFO handler.ContextHandler: stopped o.s.j.s.ServletContextHandler{/executors/threadDump/json,null}
16/01/20 20:20:59 INFO handler.ContextHandler: stopped o.s.j.s.ServletContextHandler{/executors/threadDump,null}
16/01/20 20:20:59 INFO handler.ContextHandler: stopped o.s.j.s.ServletContextHandler{/executors/json,null}
16/01/20 20:20:59 INFO handler.ContextHandler: stopped o.s.j.s.ServletContextHandler{/executors,null}
16/01/20 20:20:59 INFO handler.ContextHandler: stopped o.s.j.s.ServletContextHandler{/environment/json,null}
16/01/20 20:20:59 INFO handler.ContextHandler: stopped o.s.j.s.ServletContextHandler{/environment,null}
16/01/20 20:20:59 INFO handler.ContextHandler: stopped o.s.j.s.ServletContextHandler{/storage/rdd/json,null}
16/01/20 20:20:59 INFO handler.ContextHandler: stopped o.s.j.s.ServletContextHandler{/storage/rdd,null}
16/01/20 20:20:59 INFO handler.ContextHandler: stopped o.s.j.s.ServletContextHandler{/storage/json,null}
16/01/20 20:20:59 INFO handler.ContextHandler: stopped o.s.j.s.ServletContextHandler{/storage,null}
16/01/20 20:20:59 INFO handler.ContextHandler: stopped o.s.j.s.ServletContextHandler{/stages/pool/json,null}
16/01/20 20:20:59 INFO handler.ContextHandler: stopped o.s.j.s.ServletContextHandler{/stages/pool,null}
16/01/20 20:20:59 INFO handler.ContextHandler: stopped o.s.j.s.ServletContextHandler{/stages/stage/json,null}
16/01/20 20:20:59 INFO handler.ContextHandler: stopped o.s.j.s.ServletContextHandler{/stages/stage,null}
16/01/20 20:20:59 INFO handler.ContextHandler: stopped o.s.j.s.ServletContextHandler{/stages/json,null}
16/01/20 20:20:59 INFO handler.ContextHandler: stopped o.s.j.s.ServletContextHandler{/stages,null}
16/01/20 20:20:59 INFO handler.ContextHandler: stopped o.s.j.s.ServletContextHandler{/jobs/job/json,null}
16/01/20 20:20:59 INFO handler.ContextHandler: stopped o.s.j.s.ServletContextHandler{/jobs/job,null}
16/01/20 20:20:59 INFO handler.ContextHandler: stopped o.s.j.s.ServletContextHandler{/jobs/json,null}
16/01/20 20:20:59 INFO handler.ContextHandler: stopped o.s.j.s.ServletContextHandler{/jobs,null}
16/01/20 20:20:59 INFO ui.SparkUI: Stopped Spark web UI at http://10.xx.xx.xx:4040
16/01/20 20:20:59 INFO cluster.YarnClientSchedulerBackend: Shutting down all executors
16/01/20 20:20:59 INFO cluster.YarnClientSchedulerBackend: Interrupting monitor thread
16/01/20 20:20:59 INFO cluster.YarnClientSchedulerBackend: Asking each executor to shut down
16/01/20 20:20:59 INFO cluster.YarnClientSchedulerBackend: Stopped
16/01/20 20:20:59 INFO spark.MapOutputTrackerMasterEndpoint: MapOutputTrackerMasterEndpoint stopped!
16/01/20 20:20:59 INFO storage.MemoryStore: MemoryStore cleared
16/01/20 20:20:59 INFO storage.BlockManager: BlockManager stopped
16/01/20 20:20:59 INFO storage.BlockManagerMaster: BlockManagerMaster stopped
16/01/20 20:20:59 INFO scheduler.OutputCommitCoordinator$OutputCommitCoordinatorEndpoint: OutputCommitCoordinator stopped!
16/01/20 20:20:59 INFO spark.SparkContext: Successfully stopped SparkContext
16/01/20 20:20:59 INFO remote.RemoteActorRefProvider$RemotingTerminator: Shutting down remote daemon.
16/01/20 20:20:59 INFO remote.RemoteActorRefProvider$RemotingTerminator: Remote daemon shut down; proceeding with flushing remote transports.
16/01/20 20:20:59 INFO remote.RemoteActorRefProvider$RemotingTerminator: Remoting shut down.
16/01/20 20:20:59 INFO util.ShutdownHookManager: Shutdown hook called
16/01/20 20:20:59 INFO util.ShutdownHookManager: Deleting directory /tmp/spark-ba928a28-64a6-4c70-b4cf-8c348140e89e/httpd-7892e967-247d-469e-96fb-79ad9269e569
16/01/20 20:20:59 INFO util.ShutdownHookManager: Deleting directory /tmp/spark-ba928a28-64a6-4c70-b4cf-8c348140e89e
16/01/20 20:20:59 INFO util.ShutdownHookManager: Deleting directory /tmp/spark-ba928a28-64a6-4c70-b4cf-8c348140e89e/pyspark-a2f9af7d-c218-4a0c-ac8a-bfe446fbc754
[I 2016-01-20 20:21:01.344 zoltan.fedor restarter:103] KernelRestarter: restarting kernel (1/5)
```

And then starts repeating the above.
Also where it crashes (where it writes out the Spark version), it also shows some non-displayable characters you don't see in the above logs.

Any idea why is the crashing?

Comment: why do you need jupyterhub to connect to the hadoop cluster?

Comment: I want out data scientists to use PySpark to run Spark code on the cluster, get data returned by Spark back to their notebook, load additional data to it from local databases, etc.

Comment: JupyterHub is excellent for ondemand data analysis, which is exactly where Spark's strength lies to. So we want to use Jupyterhub for data analysis on the Spark cluster. It is a valid use case others have highlighted too.